# Need to convert an object to XML and getting an error

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

**I have this class:**

```
  <Serializable()> _

   Public Class Bonder
    ''' <summary>
    ''' General information
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public BonderName As String
    Public Serial_Number As String
    Public System_Type As String
    Public DM_Version As String
    Public RTS_Build As String
    Public RTS_Label As String
    Public CPU_Boot_Rom As String
    Public BondHead_1 As String = ""
    Public BondHead_2 As String = ""
    Public IP1 As String
    Public IP2 As String
    Public LoadedLeadFrameSetup As String
    Public LoadedMagazineHandler As String
    Public LoadedProcessProgram As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Configuration Information
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ConfigurationKVP As New ArrayList


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Devices on the Bonder
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public DevicesOnBonder As New ArrayList

    ''' <summary>
    ''' RTS server information
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ServerInfo As New ArrayList


    ''' <summary>
    ''' RTS Options selected
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Options As New ArrayList

End Class`
```

**This is my code to serialize it and put it into XML format:**

```
  Dim serializer As XmlSerializer
    serializer = New XmlSerializer(currentBonderSetup.GetType)
    Dim tw As New StreamWriter("c:\book1.xml")
    serializer.Serialize(tw, currentBonderSetup)
    tw.Close()
```

Where am I going wrong? I think the issue is from the ArrayLists but I dont know how to solve it.  the ArrayLists contain other objects that to have the Serializeable attribute.

Here are the other classes

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Configs
    Public Item As String
    Public Value As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal key As String, ByVal result As String)
        Item = key
        Value = result
    End Sub

End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class BonderDevices
    Public Device_Type As String
    Public Instance As String
    Public Board_Rev As String
    Public Software_Ver As String
    Public Status As String
    Public Data As String

End Class
<Serializable()> _
Public Class ServerInfo
    Public Type As String
    Public Value As String
End Class
```

Comment: There was an error generating the XML document.

The inner exception is :
{"BMS.Classes.Configs cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."}

I added those classes up top in my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try constructing your serializer so...

```
var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bonder), new Type[]{typeof(Configs),typeof(BonderDevices),typeof(ServerInfo)});
```

and, yeah, you need default parameterless constructors on all your types.

in VB

```
Dim s = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Bonder), New Type() {GetType(Configs), GetType(BonderDevices), GetType(ServerInfo)})
```

Comment: I get this error now:

"The type BMS.Classes+Configs was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Comment: did you try what i suggested?

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ - it isnt perfect but you can usually suss it out. I haven't written any vb professionally for a few years, a bit rusty.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameterles constructor to `Configs` ?

```
   Public Sub New()

   End Sub
```

Maybe consider giving the serializer a hint about the types, by passing an array of the types into the constructor.

Comment: well its choking on Configs and that has a constructor and it is being passed 2 parameters....

Comment: I don't think the parameterless constructor needs to be public, because it's being used internally.

Comment: i made it public and it worked... i got a different error but im going to include the other classes in the typing.